# PHPStorm 8 - Cannot run program "git"

Tags: git, phpstorm, bitbucket

I have git path setup in `PHPStorm` settings, and clicking <kbd>TEST</kbd> shows that it works fine. However trying to add repo from BitBucket in PHPStorm command line via

```
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git)
```

always gives me the error:

> "Cannot run program "git" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\User\Documents\Development\web\project"): CreateProcess
>   error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

I have now just installed latest Git, but I still get this problem.

EDIT: `git` command is recognised in windows command line. However, in PHPStorm command line it is not, but if I swap `git` for `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe` it works. Is this maybe a system variable error? Or a PHPStorm error?

Comment: 1) Try providing full path to git executable instead of just `git` (plus .. on Windows it should be at least `git.exe`). 2) If you have installed git while IDE was running (and still running) try log off and log on again -- IDE may still see old PATH).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On windows cmd line "git" is a recognised command.  In PHPStorm git path is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe I have tried restarting PHPStorm. Still getting error.

Comment: However if I use the full path to git (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe) instead of just git, as you suggested, it works.

Comment: *"On windows cmd line "git" is a recognised command."* That's because command shell (cmd.exe) is searching for git.exe, git.com, git.cmd, git.bat and so on (as per `PATHEXT` environment variable) until it finds it. But if task is executed directly (`CreateNewProcess()`) then Windows does not do such search (no cmd.exe is involved here).